# Determine potential index of an item if it were put into an array and sorted.

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, lodash

Can it be done faster than cloning array, pushing the item and sorting?

I've got an `array` of items, and an `item` that's not part of the array:

```
let array = [
  {name: 'Foo'},
  {name: 'Bar'},
  {name: 'Quux},
]

let item = {name: 'Baz'}
```

The array is sorted alphabetically:

```
array = _.sortBy(array, 'name')
```

Same with vanilla JS:

```
function compare ({name: a}, {name: b}) {
  return (
    a < b ? -1 :
    a > b ?  1 :
             0
  )
}

array.sort(compare)
```

**My goal is to figure out at which index the `item` would end up if it were pushed into the `array` and the `array` were sorted again the same way.**

An obvious solution is to try and see:

```
function getProposedItemIndex (array, item) {
  let tempArray = array.slice() // copy the array, we don't want to mutate the existing one
  tempArray.push(item)
  tempArray.sort(compare) // or `tempArray = _.sortBy(tempArray, 'name')`
  return tempArray.indexOf(item)
}
```

But this seems to be non-optimal.

**Is there a way to do it efficiently while keeping the code concise and readable?** I. e. without hard to comprehend stuff like `for (let i; i>array.length; i++) {}`. A lodash chain would be ideal.

Comment: Is the input array already sorted before the new element is added? Then all you’d need to do is to loop over the existing array, and check when your new item becomes “greater” than the current one, at which point you can break out of the loop ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `array` is sorted, then we can use [`lodash#sortedIndexBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortedIndexBy) to get the index.

```
var index = _.sortedIndexBy(array, item, 'name');
```

```js
let array = [
  {name: 'Bar'},
  {name: 'Foo'},
  {name: 'Quux'},
];

let item = {name: 'Baz'};

var index = _.sortedIndexBy(array, item, 'name');

console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var index=0;
while(compare(array[index],item)>0) index++;
if(index===array.length) index=-1;
```

In action:

```js
let array = [
  {name: 'Foo'},
  {name: 'Bar'},
  {name: 'Quux'},
].sort(compare);

let item = {name: 'Baz'};

function compare ({name: a}, {name: b}) {
  return (
    a < b ? -1 :
    a > b ?  1 :
             0
  )
}

var index=0;
while(compare(array[index],item)>0) index++;
if(index===array.length) index=-1;
console.log(index);
```

Comment: Nice! This relies on an idea that the array is already sorted, right? Could this conditional work: `array[index].name > item.name` in case I used lodash to sort and don't have `compare` at hand?

Comment: @lolmaus yes. no *while(array[index].name < item.name) index++* <= find the first position were the arrays elem is bigger

Comment: Congrats with 10K. Was hoping to be responsible for you reaching 10K, but StackOverflow delayed my bounty.